# Java Arbitrary Expression Evaluator?

Tags: java, expression, evaluator

Write the Java code for an arbitrary expression evaluator (supporting _, -, *, /). The - and / operator only works on two operands, the others can have any number or operands. The / operator will additionally check that there is no 0 in the second operand. If it does, then it will throw a BadArithmeticException.

Write the code using the Composite pattern. Also write a client class that will create objects and calculate expressions to demonstrate the use of the composite pattern. The common method in the composite hierarchy is called eval. Here is the signature for eval.

public int eval() throws BadArithmeticException { ...

Not really sure where to begin here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you written any Java code before?

Comment: I have, but I have never used anything like this before.  Mostly more simple stuff.

Never used composite pattern or exceptions before, first of all.

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: Give it a try yourself. If you get stuck, show us what you have and ask a specific question.

Comment: Do you know what [Composite Pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/composite-design-pattern-java-0) is?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a question but I can offer a suggestion at least. I would start by trying to write your exception so that you understand what you should be doing. You can find this in the Oracle docs here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/creating.html

If you know that you can't divide by 0, think about what kinds of expressions a user (or you) could input that would cause a BadArithmeticException.